Continuous Markov Chains (James Norris)
This is from Markov Chains by James Norris. He is trying to motivate continuous time Markov chains using the following concept (page 61-62):
We may think of the discrete parameter space $ \{0, 1, 2, \dots\} $ as embedded in the continuous parameter space $ [0, \infty) $. For $ p \in (0, \infty) $, a natural way to interpolate the discrete sequence $ (p^n : n = 0, 1, 2, \dots) $ is by the function $ (e^{tq} : t \geq 0) $, where $ q = \log p $. Consider now a finite set $ I $ and a matrix
$$
P = (p_{ij} : i, j \in I).
$$
Is there a natural way to fill in the gaps in the discrete sequence $ (P^n : n = 0, 1, 2, \dots) $?
For any matrix $ Q = (q_{ij} : i, j \in I) $, the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{Q^k}{k!}
$$
converges componentwise, and we denote its limit by $ e^Q $. Moreover, if two matrices $ Q_1 $ and $ Q_2 $ commute, then
$$
e^{Q_1 + Q_2} = e^{Q_1} e^{Q_2}.
$$
The proofs of these assertions follow the scalar case closely and are given in [Section 2.10]. Suppose then that we can find a matrix $ Q $ with $ e^Q = P $. Then
$$
e^{nQ} = (e^Q)^n = P^n
$$
so $ (e^{tQ} : t \geq 0) $ fills in the gaps in the discrete sequence.
I do not understand what he means by "fill in the gaps in the discrete sequence $ (p^n : n = 0, 1, 2, \dots) $ ?" And how is that related to continuous time?
